# java CDI injection how to annotate and modify third part class

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I'm new to java CDI, I'm wondering how can I annotate a third party class when I inject it.

For example, I would like to inject jackson `ObjectMapper` into many of my services, and I would like to register some customized serializer, what I can do is write a method and mark as `@PostConstruct` but only when I can access its code. I think this scenario is quite common when injecting some third part class but would like to do some customization on them. What's a common practice in java CDI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a producer.

I use this often for creation of loggers like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class LoggerProducer {
   @Produces
   public Logger getLogger(InjectionPoint ip) {
      // only include the injection point if you need it
      return LoggerFactory.getLogger(ip.getBean().getBeanClass().getSimpleName());
   }
}

...

@Inject
private Logger logger;
```

Comment: in the example above, how did the container manager know which `ip` param to pass in? Should we also specify the param value in the place we inject it?

Comment: @ZiqiLiu The injection point is a meta object describing the location where the injection takes place. This is added automatically by the container manager. But you can simply leave this parameter out of the producer if you don't need any of this information.